# cannot resolve symbol SmsManager.getDefault()

Tags: android, android-studio, smsmanager

```
package com.soft.mash.contactmanager;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.SmsManager;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class SendSms extends Activity {

    SmsManager smsManager ;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    public boolean SendMessage(String number, String textMessage) {
        try {
            smsManager = (SmsManager) new SmsManager.getDefault();
            smsManager.sendTextMessage(number, null, textMessage, null, null);
            return true;
        }catch (Exception e)
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"SMS sending failed",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Why

```
cannot resolve symbol 'getDefault()'
```

is occurring here?

In one similar StackOverflow question's answer advised to "Invalidate Cache and restart". But not solving my problem here.

Comment: use smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault(); instead of TypeCasting

Comment: @NickIsaacs, thanks. Solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I was doing wrong here is I was trying to create new `Instance` of `SmsManager` by using `new`. But the things here needed is to only get the default `Instance` of `SmsManager`.

Answer (score 2):

Use `smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();` instead of type casting